# Модальное окно и табы

Tags: javascript

```
for(let i=0;i<modalBtn.length;i++){        
    modalBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        console.log(i);
        let target=e.target;
        if(target&&target.classList.contains('description-btn')){
          for(let i=0;i<modalBtn.length;i++){              
              if(target==modalBtn[i]){
                overlay.style.display="block";
                break;
              }
          }
        }
    });//переписать
}
```

Как данный код понимает, что я нажимаю на именно данный таб? Он должен выводить модальное окно при нажатии на кнопку в табе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас тут наблюдается некоторая избыточность

В объекте описывающем событие (`e`), вы считываете поле `target`

```
let target=e.target;
```

оно указывает на источник события - элемент на который Вы кликнули

а так же вы используете индекс элемента в массиве, можно было бы обойтись и без этого.

Я не исправлял Ваш код, просто немного дополнил его, избыточность предлагаю удалить Вам самим

```js
let modalBtn = [...document.querySelectorAll('button')]
for(let i=0;i<modalBtn.length;i++){        
    modalBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        console.log(i);
        let target=e.target;
        if(target&&target.classList.contains('description-btn')){
          for(let i=0;i<modalBtn.length;i++){              
              if(target==modalBtn[i]){
              overlay.innerHTML = 'Нажата кнопка ' + i;
                overlay.style.display="block";
                break;
              }
          }
        }
    });//переписать
}
```

```html
<button class='description-btn'>1</button>
<button class='description-btn'>2</button>
<button class='description-btn'>3</button>
<button class='description-btn'>4</button>
<div id='overlay' style='display:none; width:100%; height:100%; position: absolute; top:0;left:0; background-color:white'>1234</div>
```

Comment: А мой код правильно написан? Или как-то можно его переделать?

Comment: @DenisShestopalov он слегка избыточен..